# Can someone explain intel(R) 82567V-4 gigabit network connection?

Tags: networking, connection, gigabit-ethernet

I don't know much about networks connection but I am working on a project for a class that requires solving a slow connection issue.  Could someone explain what intel(R) 82567V-4 gigabit network connection actually means?  Is this the connection available to use or the connection it's currently getting?

Comment: It's just the name of the device. It has no connection to what's available or even what the current speed is, though network devices are frequently named after their maximum line speed.

Comment: We don't help with homework here at SU.

Answer (score 1):

intel(R) 82567V-4 gigabit network card is a physical device on your computer, Gigabit is the bandwidth that this card available to work on. Also, it doesn't mean you already have a Gigabit connection. It depends your network source/provider. such as a Gigabit router can get Gigabit level access between your computer and router. Speed between router and provider defined your actually speed.

Usually, for home or small business, provider only provide 10Mb-100Mb bandwidth. Much slower than your local access speed (local: computer to router). So the actually network transfer speed can be calculate as below:

provider bandwidth 80 Mb / 8 = 10 MB download speed.